# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to make a simple Image Classifier using Tensorflow. 
From here
https://medium.com/@linjunghsuan/create-a-simple-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-a7061635984a

I am using Anaconda2 on Windows 10 (64bit)
Packages used 
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
certifi:        2016.2.28-py35_0
pip:            9.0.3-py35_1
python:         3.5.4-0
setuptools:     36.4.0-py35_1
vc:             14-0
vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25420-0
wheel:          0.29.0-py35_0
wincertstore:   0.2-py35_0
```

I downloaded retrain.py from 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

When I am trying to train the data using

```
python {$your-working_directory}/retrain.py
```

I am getting these errors

```
[tensorflow] C:\Users\user>python F:\Tensorflow\retrain.py
ERROR:tensorflow:Image directory '' not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Tensorflow\retrain.py", line 1409, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "F:\Coursera ML\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "F:\Tensorflow\retrain.py", line 1061, in main
    class_count = len(image_lists.keys())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

In F:\Tensorflow there is one folder with the dataset images and the retrain.py

I am a beginner and this is my first time using Tensorflow and Deep Learning. 
I scrubbed through StackOverflow and Github but I couldnt find any solution that worked. 
I think i am making an error with the directories of the images of the data set. 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.
(Also if you need additional information regarding anything please do let me know)

Comment: Try setting the image directory: ./retrain.py --image-dir <directory_name>

Comment: your image_list is empty ,using keys() on it returns None, try to see if you get the images correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supplying all the required parameters in the command line

Windows example from the post you linked:
[example](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*TyIlJnUlpkI42Qb9uFHWIA.png) (SO won't let me post images. )

If the file is stored in `C:\training_data` and assuming your working directory is `F:\Tensorflow` then the command is

`python F:\Tensorflow\retrain.py --image_dir C:\training_data --how_many_training_steps 500 --model_dir F:\Tensorflow\inception --output_graph=F:\Tensorflow\retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=F:\Tensorflow\retrained_labels.txt`

Comment: Encountered a few small errors after that. But it worked for me thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**For MAC users who found same error**

Solution of "Palash Taneja" can help (Paths will be different on mac):

Example command for MAC users to make training model from images:

```
python3 code/retrain.py --image_dir flower_photos --bottleneck_dir=bottleneck --how_many_training_steps 500 --model_dir=model --output_graph=graph/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=graph/retrained_labels.txt
```

*File and directory tree of terminal's working directory: (Here ML is working directory)*

ML/code/retain.py

ML/flower_photos/{various dir of flowers or any images}

ML/graph

ML/model

ML/bottleneck